# How to disable Photoswipe Animation for Thumbnails

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, photoswipe

I do have square thumbnails and due to the animation on clicking on thumbnails the large images are not shown properly because they are stretched.

So I would like to disable the zoom-animation for thumbnails.

How do I have to set these settings?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this option:

```
allowUserZoom = false
```

Comment: no that is unfortunately not working ... I think it's for disabling zoom on the pictures